# Angular routing (link) is not working in HTML

Tags: angular, rest, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a REST API to do CRUD operations. I am adding a route in Angular CLI to add employees but it is not working.

In app.module.ts the component is present.
It is working for other components.

The add-employee link is also not being clicked in the angular app.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './create-employee/create-employee.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  /** specify /employees will show which content  */
  { path : 'employees' , component : EmployeeListComponent} , 

  { path : 'create-employee' , component: CreateEmployeeComponent},
  { path : '' , redirectTo: 'employees' , pathMatch: 'full' } 
 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app-component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a router-Link="employees" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Employee List</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a router-Link="create-employee" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Add Employee</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try removing the hyphen in `routerLink` in your html, `routerLink="/create-employee"`

Comment: Yes , now its working . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be `[routerLink]="['/your-path']"`.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/employees']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Employee List</a>

<a [routerLink]="['/create-employee']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Add Employee</a>
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4gwsm2)

---

### Reference:

[RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#routerlink)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `routerLink=""` rather than `router-Link=""`
So the entire code goes like -

```
<a routerLink="/employees" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Employee List</a>
<a routerLink="/create-employee" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link"> Add Employee</a>
```

And I hope you have entered `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` this too.